# How do I fix this command in python for a simple calculator

Tags: python

```
first = input("What is your first number?(type x to do nothing) ")
second = input("What is your second number?(type x to do nothing) ")

if first == "x":
    first = None

if second == "x":
    second = None

if first and second == "x":
    print("You have not used any numbers. Disabling calculator...")
    sys.exit()

first = float(first)
second = float(second)
```

This is a part of my code in a calculator but it doesn't like to function the way I want it to be.

I'm trying to make the python code shut itself down when the user inputs "x" at the two variables. When I try to do it, python sends me an error saying:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Any help?

Comment: When they type 'x' youre making input=None and then trying to convert None to a float.

Comment: Also the `if first and second == "x"` doesnt do what you think it does

Answer (score 3):

To check if 2 variables are equals to something, you must run the 2 tests

```
if first=="x" and second=="x":
```

But as you have modified the  to `None` they can't be `x` anymore, it should be the following

```
if first is None and second is None:
```

---

The 2 choices you have are

1. Give a default if just one is not given

   ```
   if first == "x" and second == "x":
       print("You have not used any numbers. Disabling calculator...")
       sys.exit()
   elif first == "x":
       first = 0
   elif second == "x":
       second = 0

   first = float(first)
   second = float(second)
   ```
2. Stop the program even if just one of the 2 is `x`

   ```
   if first == "x" or second == "x":
       print("You have not used any numbers. Disabling calculator...")
       sys.exit()

   first = float(first)
   second = float(second)
   ```

---

As it's not in the question but a good sugestion for help you out : verify that the value is numeric

```
any(map(str.isnumeric, [first, first.strip("-+")]))
```

- test that either the value itself, or the value without the sign
- is just numeric : only digit and dot
- `any` to either get it for the value or the value without a sign

Comment: I would also consider changing the verifying to just check if the string is numeric or not in it's entirety. This will allow you to input positive and negative numbers: `any(map(str.isnumeric, [first, first.strip("-+")]))`

Answer (score -5):

Change:
if first and second == "x":

to :
if first and second == None :

Comment: This is both wrong, and doesnt adress the source of the error. Check my comments above. The if should be `if first==None and second==None`